# Jumbotron GRAB/ZOOM

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

How to grab or zoom an image inside a jumbotron? 
[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/C4Sjg/461/)

HTML:

```
<div class="page-header">
<h1>Jumbotron <small>how to make grabbale?</small></h1>
</div>
<div class="jumbotron" style="">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.jumbotron {
    position: relative;
    background: #000 url("http://www.w3schools.com/images/w3schools_green.jpg") center center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 512px;
    background-size: cover;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use transform scale.

```
-moz-transform: scale(1.5);
-webkit-transform: scale(1.5);
transform: scale(1.5);
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/C4Sjg/462/)

Comment: Nice attempt. That is a hover effect. I am looking for a script rather that would enable me to grab and zoom without effecting the fixed height of the element.

Comment: I zoomed it with scale (1,1) and on hover there is also zoom (2.0). Have you any example how this should look? Because I really don't know exactly what do you want to achieve.

Comment: I like how it can scale. I want the user to have the option to zoom in or out based on a onclick event (using a button). As for the grab I simply want the user to have the freedom to reposition the image inside the jumbotron.